# Why can I no longer (un)install packages via apt-get after doing a partial dist-upgrade?

Tags: apt, mdadm

I (stupidly) ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, which partially succeeded, but now I get output similar to this every time I try to (un)install a package:

Here, for instance, is the output of `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge postgres*`:

```
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic (3.13.0-43.72) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
W: mdadm: the array /dev/md/monolith:0 with UUID 826ef9b8:1c282186:82586683:e0b960b3
W: mdadm: is currently active, but it is not listed in mdadm.conf. if
W: mdadm: it is needed for boot, then YOUR SYSTEM IS NOW UNBOOTABLE!
W: mdadm: please inspect the output of /usr/share/mdadm/mkconf, compare
W: mdadm: it to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and make the necessary changes.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-43-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 38: /etc/default/grub: function: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's the output of `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf`:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
```

And here's the output of `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=c13ebb40:55db4a69:108822c5:5ee02f0b name=htpc:0

# This file was auto-generated on Thu, 11 Jun 2015 00:15:47 +0200
# by mkconf $Id$
```

What's my next move?

**Edit:** It should be noted that I have no problem rebooting, as I'm not booting to RAID.

Comment: @markkirby, my current kernel is `3.13.0-54-generic`.  I would be perfectly fine downgrading to `3.13.0-43-generic` if that solved my issue.

Comment: @markkirby, just to be clear, did you mean `3.13.0-54-generic` ?

Comment: @markkirby, okay I've moved `initrd.img-3.13.0-54-generic` to another directory and rerun my command.  I'm getting identical output.  I've also tried this with `...43-generic`, but no dice.

Comment: In short, move linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic, your current kernel is fine as you can boot

Comment: @markkirby, ah okay, I was confused since you wrote `initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic` rather than `...43-generic`.  That said, I've tried moving `initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic` and re-running my command and I'm getting identical output.  Further, I don't see any file called `linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic` in `/boot`

Comment: @markkirby, no problem!  Unfortunately, I get exactly the same behavior when moving `/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub
update-grub
sudo apt-get -f install
```

seems to have fixed the issue.  I'm still not exactly sure why things got screwy in the first place, but hopefully this might save someone else's butt...